# Charge or Charges on the oil droplets?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, measurements, charge, discrete

Due to my poor understanding of various paper and other material provided by google on [Millikan's oil drop experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment) I ask the following question here.

1. As the drops were charged by either friction or x-ray radiation or both, how did they ensure that they found out the charge of a **single** electron? For all we can say it just as well may have been 2 or more electrons!
2. Also even after the drops were charged by lets say a single electron (in excess) how could one be sure that it did not form a dipole? Why assume spherical symmetry?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96254/2451

Answer (score 1):

The charges are all integer multiples of $e$. In the experiment you record many measurements of the charge and you look for the biggest number that divides into all the measured charges an integer number of times. Unless you are extremely unlucky the number you end up with is the electron charge (it's possible you might end up with $2e$ or $3e$, but this is extremely unlikely if you have a lot of measurements).

Comment: Won't there be any other reason to confirm that charge on one electron as e , like specifically with any math proof. And does this experiment suggest that electron has no constituent particles, even if it did have, is it that they remain settled like quarks in protons and neutrons? Would applying high electric field make constituents (if they were present) of electron rush out? Is there any specific reason for considering electron as elementary particle?

Comment: @VINAY The electron is an elementary particle because no structure  within the experimental resolution has been found in the scattering experiments at high energy. You must remember that it was the rutherford scattering that told us the atom had a core, the analogous scattering told us the proton has three quarks. The electron has shown no such substructure in equivalent experiments. The limit of its size is very much smaller than nuclear dimensions http://gabrielse.physics.harvard.edu/gabrielse/overviews/ElectronSubstructure/ElectronSubstructure.html <1^-18 m .

Comment: @VINAY this experiment is on composite objects the electrons riding on the oil drop. It is scattering experiments that are done one electron at a time.